# How do I zoom the map in and out in Far Cry 2?

Tags: far-cry-2

I used to know how to zoom the map in and out in Far Cry 2 (PC version).  It was an undocumented control bound to one of the other controls in the game.

Now I can't remember what it is.  Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not having the game at hand right now, I think it was Reload.

Comment: If you remove 'right-click' from your answer, I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

After pushing every button (and killing myself with an accidentally-thrown grenade) I discovered that the correct button is "reload".

**Pressing reload while having the map open will change the zoom in Far Cry 2.**

Answer (score 2):

its R OR your customized reload button